# Retrieving Primary Key from Entity Framework entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

Entity Framework (version 6) generates classes based on your tables that look like this (where each property represents a field in the table):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("dbo.MyTable")]
public partial class MyTable {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MyTableID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string SomeColumn { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I decided to provide a little more functionality, specifically a way to return an array containing the primary key of any given table. A primary key can be made up of multiple fields, and each field can be a different type. I came up with the following, using reflection and LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

public abstract class Entity 
{
    public object[] PrimaryKey
    {
        get
        {
            return (from property in this.GetType().GetProperties()
                    where Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(KeyAttribute))
                    orderby ((ColumnAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(false).Single(
                        attr => attr is ColumnAttribute)).Order ascending
                    select property.GetValue(this)).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I then modify each of my Entity Framework table classes to inherit Entity (ie `public partial class MyTable : Entity { ... }`), so they get the PrimaryKey functionality.

A return type of `object[]` made the most sense - EntityFramework's `DbSet` has functions such as `Find(params object[] args)`, where the return value of my `PrimaryKey` property slots neatly in.

First time using LINQ, and I'm not hugely experienced with reflection, attributes or the Entity Framework. Are there any problems/gotchas with this, or any improvements?

Comment: two things to care about. This won't work if with code-first + fluent mappings (no attributes), and the order of properties in a compound key is not guaranteed. Maybe you should explain in what circumstances you need this for us to propose any improvements.

Comment: I added an `orderby` to the query to ensure the column order (this means that every `[Key]` field also requires a `[Column(Order = n)]` attribute, but Entity Framework does this anyway. Of course, this solution requires EF's attributes on the fields - without them I believe it would be impossible to determine the primary key in any case.

Comment: Instead of manualy modify each class to inherit from the Entity class you could use a T4 template. Check the following urls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Someone already answer this question in here, so move to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141955/entityframework-6-how-to-get-identity-field-with-reflection